# How many sequential partitions (defined inside) are there of numbers 1...n?

Tags: combinatorics

So, suppose $[n] = \{1,\cdots,n\}$. A partition of $[n]$ is just any division of $[n]$ into non-overlapping sets. Suppose instead of partition $[n]$ into sets I partitioned it into sequences. So {1,2,3,4,5} could be partitioned into {(1,2),(3,4,5)} or {(2,1),(3,4,5)} and others. How many partitions of $[n]$ into sequences exist?

Comment: Do you know about http://oeis.org ? If you have the first values of the number of partitions you can type them there and see if the sequence is known.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

The combinatorial species for sets of sequences is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{S}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
This gives the generating function
$$G(z) = \exp \frac{z}{1-z}$$
and the closed form
$$n! [z^n] G(z) = n! [z^n] \exp\frac{z}{1-z}.$$
This yields the sequence
$$1, 3, 13, 73, 501, 4051, 37633, 394353, 4596553, 58941091,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A000262](https://oeis.org/A000262),
where a detailed set of references and data awaits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe sequenced partitions are counted using ordered Bell numbers.

These may be computed through a summation formula for Stirling numbers of the second kind. An $n$-element set contains the $n$th ordered Bell number of sequenced partitions:

$$a_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {k!} \left\{{n}\atop{k}\right\}$$

where the Stirling numbers are explicitly generated by the formula:

$$\left\{{n}\atop{k}\right\} = \frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}\binom{n}{k}j^n$$

Comment: I don't think this is write. This seems to begin by partitioning the $[n]$ and then ordering the partitions with respect to other partitions. What I want is to partition $n$ and order the elements within each partition. For instance, this counts ({1,2}, {3,4,5}) and ({3,4,5}, {1,2}) as different partitions instead of counting {(1,2), (3,4,5)} an {(2,1), (3,4,5)} as different partitions