# enumerating all permutations of partitions

Tags: permutations, set-partition

Given a set of $n$ items, I would like to enumerate *all* the permutations of *all* the partitions of those $n$ items. For example, in the case of $n=3$ (with Bell number 5), there are 13 permutations of interest:

```
{1,2,3}
{1}{2,3}
{2,3}{1}
{1,2}{3}
{3}{1,2}
{1,3}{2}
{2}{1,3}
{1}{2}{3}
{1}{3}{2}
{2}{1}{3}
{2}{3}{1}
{3}{1}{2}
{3}{2}{1}
```

As I understand it, this is not simply a $k$-combinations numbering problem because the size of the subsets is not constrained. Similarly, I don't think(?) this is simply a symmetric group of order $n$.

There is obviously a fairly trivial algorithm that will work here: generate all of the $B_n$ partitions, find $|P|!$ for each partition $P$, and sum. I am wondering if there is a more general solution, and if it possibly has a name or formulation I'm not aware of.

Comment: There is a detailed discussion of these at the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421886/ordered-set-partitions/). I am not sure if this would be considered a duplicate.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: For those who may come across this in the future: the term [ordered Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) is probably what you're looking for. Search MSE for [several](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625703/how-many-linear-order-types-are-there-on-a-set-of-n-elements/625717#625717) [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042276/how-many-sequential-partitions-defined-inside-are-there-of-numbers-1-n/1042319#1042319) [threads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371296/how-to-calculate-combinations-count-for-this-problem/1371351#1371351).